# How can I prevent my local files, which are deleted and ignored in remote repo, being deleted when pull from git?

Tags: git

There were some files should be ignored by git in my git repo. 
So I did this to remove them from the repo on my PC.

```
git rm some-local-only-config --cache
echo "some-local-only-config" >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "ignore xxxx"
git push origin master
```

Now I want others to pull the latest changes into their PC but keep their own local files that I deleted from git repo when pulling the changes.

How can they do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not very easily...

If this is also a file in the other users git repo (which i assume it is) then they will also need to do add it to their .gitignore and then `git rm some-local-only-config --cache` and commit that (to match your change but not actually delete the file) so that when they pull the change is not re-applied (and therefore not delete).

I would say if its just a file or two (or a single folder) just copy it out of the git folder before pulling - its way simpler!